# javascript read first five values

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I am fetching some values in a `forEach` clause

```
 data.forEach(function(content){
  ...
  controller.setAttribute(value from data);
  ...}
```

This works for me. But data loop iterates for close to 20 times. And my controller can take only 5 values. Hence my controller in above example is taking `last five` values.

How can I limit my data to exit after reading `first five` values. I need to be having some counter there right?

Or is there any other way for controller to read only `first five`?

Comment: Using counter would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an index argument after the value argument and use that:

```
data.forEach(function(content, index){
   if (index < 5) {
       controller.setAttribute(value from data);
   }
});
```

Comment: I have selected your answer as its simpler to place a index, rather than other answers given. I did it slightly different than urs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript's [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```
data.slice(0, 5).forEach(function (content){
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I gave you a +1 but the solution is slightly different from what you explained. i.e it dint work for me as my structure is different. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand properly, this should work:

```
for (i=0; i<Math.min(data.length, 5); ++i) {
  controller.setAttribute(value from data[i])
}
```

But since you seem to be using an implementation that has `Array.forEach`, so will this:

```
data.slice(0,5).forEach(function(content) {
   controller.setAttribute(value from content)
}
```

Comment: answer is good, but I have a simpler solution. I gave you a +1 though. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [ECMA `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), the callback receives three arguments, the second being the index.

```
data.forEach(function(content, index) {
   if (index >= 5) return;
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ECMA. I gave a you a +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter or a for loop for this. Example:

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    controller.setAttribute(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: yes it does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach :-)

Comment: @SealVieira missed on that one :D That's why I love stackoverflow, you always learn something